# Access to grid columns by name not index

Tags: asp.net, gridview, grid

Is it possible to access grid column by name not by index `grid.columns["name"]` because if I add new column I must change all numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per row, you could use something like the following to get the index by name, and then use that to access the correct column.

```
int GetColumnIndexByName(GridViewRow row, string searchColumnName)
{
    int columnIndex = 0;
    foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        if (cell.ContainingField is BoundField)
        {
            if (((BoundField)cell.ContainingField).DataField.Equals(searchColumnName))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        columnIndex++;
    }
    return columnIndex;
}
```

Either way you need to create helper methods to go by name instead of the index.